# How to get the toggle button to only show on a specific width in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I would like my toggle button to only show when the screen hits around 650px so that would be when it's in the col-xs section, I think.

My code is

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-pull-1 col-sm-7 col-xs-5">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#menu" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div id="menu" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" style="">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills menu">
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=2">ABOUT US</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=3">PORTFOLIO</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav_item">
                <a href="http://localhost:8888/Quadrature-cms/index.php?section=4">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome on SO Chibi! Have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

Answer (score 2):

One way is CSS media queries.

If I understood you correctly, I think you can write you styling within a media query like this. 
play around with `display` property to hide/show.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:650px){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [CSS media Queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/use-media-queries?hl=en) for understanding. But, basically you should do something like following:

**CSS**

```
.navbar-toggle {
    display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width/min-width: 650px) { 
    .navbar-toggle {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: I put "max-width/min-width" because I don't know if you want to display it below or above this width. So you should choose the one which matches your needs